# array_reverse() does not re-order subarray

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Can someone help me with some PHP please.

The original code ~works, but the output is in the wrong order.
So I need to REVERSE the sequence/order of the JSON array.

But when I try to reverse the sequence with PHP (extract) code below:

```
$json = file_get_contents($url,0,null,null); 
$tmp = json_decode($json, true);    // using a temp variable for testing
$result = array_reverse($tmp);      //  <--new line to reverse the arrray

foreach ($result['data'] as $event) {
    echo '<div>'.$event['name'].'</div>';
```

It doesnt reverse the output sequence.

What am I doing wrong?
Is there another/better way?

PS - I can do it in Javascript, but I need to do it server-side.

Comment: This question has been closed as Off-topic: Typo because the asker is already aware of how to use square brace syntax to access an array element -- proven by `$result['data']`.  The trivial mistake made was not accessing the `data` element when calling `array_reverse()`.  It is unnecessary to point the asker to a page that demonstrates how to access an array element.  This was a simple developer mistake.  I am explaining this closure so that there is no future argument about why "typo" was used as the close reason.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You do the reversion, but on the wrong field. You want to reverse the `data` fields instead of the array:

```
$json = file_get_contents($url); 
$tmp = json_decode($json, true);    // using a temp variable for testing
$result = $tmp;
$result['data'] = array_reverse($result['data']);

foreach ($result['data'] as $event) {
    echo '<div>'.$event['name'].'</div>';
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to reverse the content of the `$tmp['data']` array, not `$tmp` itself.

```
$json = file_get_contents($url); 
$tmp = json_decode($json, true);
$result = array_reverse($tmp['data']);

unset($tmp);

foreach ($result as $event) {
  echo '<div>'.$event['name'].'</div>';
}
```